# How to push after merge back to master?

Tags: git, gitlab

I wanted to merge a branch into master and followed the steps gitlab told me to do.

1. git fetch origin
2. git checkout -b "testbranch" "origin/testbranch"
3. git fetch origin
4. git checkout "origin/master"
5. git merge --no-ff "testbranch"
6. Here I fixed all the conflicts
7. git commit -m "merged"
8. git push origin "master"

The problem is that when trying to push to master it will say that it is already uptodate. Also the git console doesn't say that I am on the master branche but on some number "61684d2...".

How can I push my changes back to master?

Comment: It seems Merge is not done properly. Try reflogging and do it again.

Comment: `git checkout "origin/master"` puts you in "detached HEAD state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `git checkout origin/master`, you  are starting to run *locally* from a remote branch.... this is on `detached HEAD` state. If this is *really* the way you merge/push, then you need to specify where to push when pushing:

```
git push origin @:master
```

You can get away with a much shorter workflow than the one you used there like this:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master # starting to work with a detached HEAD
git merge -m "merging something" origin/another-branch
# solve conflicts and wrap up the commit if needed... when you are done with the commit:
git push upstream @:master
```

Comment: It's just how gitlab told me to do on the merge request. Never done that before. But with this I was able to push it :)

Comment: In that case, Gitlab has *awful* instructions on how to merge locally. It should just be `git switch master; git merge feature-branch; git push`, possibly fix merge conflicts before `git push`. That convoluted way of merging locally pasted into the OP question is absolutely asinine. I don't understand it. It's even plain *wrong* and is not at all what we would want to do. I have a hard time believing that's the verbatim instructions.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the recipe you provided there is how gitlab *advices* to go around with feature branches because it's cumbersome (just in case, I am not saying it's *impossible*.... it's possible, just... _unlikely_) _but_ I did not want to go around trying to show you how to be more atraight forward with the worlfow.... I just wanted to answer the technical question of how to  do the push in the finql step. Let me provide a much shorter workflow for that merge/push

Answer (score 0):

If you started your workflow from on `master`, you really only need to do the following steps:

1. `git pull`
2. `git checkout -b "testbranch" "origin/testbranch"`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git merge --no-ff "testbranch"`
5. Fix conficts
6. `git commit` (I would leave off the -m here, git's generated message is pretty useful for merge commits
7. `git push`

Basically, rather than working on a remote branch, you update your local master branch doing all the work there and the you would be able to push as you expect.